# DQN model (Game: Atari PongNoFrameskip) does not learn

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm trying to implement a DQN model of Pong game. However, it still performs like random activities even after about 1000 episodes. The CNN training seems not improve the agents.

Here is my main code:

I create a CNN including three convolution layers after pooling and three forward connection layers. the input channels is the number of pre-processed frame (from 3*210*160 to 4*84*84 and the channel is 4):

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, s_channels, a_space):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(s_channels,out_channels=32,kernel_size=8,stride=4)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,64,4,2)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64,64,3,1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*4*4,1024)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024,512)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512,a_space)

  def forward(self,input):
    output = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(input)))
    output = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(output)))
    output = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(output)))
    output = output.view(-1,64*4*4)
    output = F.relu(self.fc1(output))
    output = F.relu(self.fc2(output))
    output = F.relu(self.fc3(output))
    return output
```

After that, I construct an agent class with action selection and CNN training functions. In CNN training function, I use the batch input to come out the loss value instead of step-by-step for-loop iteration of batch data. before coming out the loss and backward, I transform the input image data into vectors of batch size. Here is the agent class:

```
class Agent():
  def __init__(self, s_space, a_space, device) -> None:

    # set GPU device to cuda
    self.device = device

    # define parameters
    self.epsilon = 1.0
    self.min_epsilon = 0.01
    self.dr = 0.995
    self.lr = 0.001
    self.gamma = 0.9

    # define models
    self.evl_net = CNN(s_space, a_space).to(self.device)
    self.tgt_net = CNN(s_space, a_space).to(self.device)
    self.cert = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
    self.optimal = th.optim.Adam(self.evl_net.parameters(),lr=self.lr)

    # define memory store
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)

  # pre-process the input image data
  def data_pre_process(self,batch_size):
    s_v = []
    a_v = []
    next_s_v = []
    r_v = []
    dones = []
    materials = random.sample(self.memory,batch_size)
    for t in materials:
      s_v.append(t[0])
      a_v.append(t[1])
      next_s_v.append(t[2])
      r_v.append(t[3])
      dones.append(t[4])

    s_v = th.Tensor(s_v).to(self.device)         
    a_v = th.LongTensor(a_v).unsqueeze(1).to(self.device)                                 
    r_v = th.FloatTensor(r_v).to(device)        
    # print(r_v.shape)
    return s_v, a_v, next_s_v, r_v, dones      

  # record the transformed images
  def record(self,tpl):
    self.memory.append(tpl)
  
  # select actions according to the states (input images with 4 channels)
  def select(self,state,a_space):
    actions = self.evl_net(state).data.tolist()
    if(random.random() <= self.epsilon):
      action = random.randint(0,a_space-1)
    else:
      action = actions.index(max(actions))
    return action

  # save CNN model
  def save(self):
    th.save(self.evl_net.state_dict(), "./Pong.pth")

  # at the beginning load the saved CNN model
  def load(self,s_channels, a_space):
    self.evl_net = CNN(s_channels, a_space).to(self.device)
    self.evl_net.load_state_dict(th.load("./Pong.pth"))

  # DQN replay progression
  def train(self,state,batch_size):
    """
    s_v_size: [batch_size,4,84,84] type: Tensor
    s_a_size: [batch_size,1] type: Tensor
    next_s_v_size: [batch_size,4,84,84] type: List
    r_v_size: [1,batch_size] type: Tensor
    dones_size: [batch_size] type: List

    """
    s_v,a_v,next_s_v,r_v,dones = self.data_pre_process(batch_size)
    self.tgt_net.load_state_dict(self.evl_net.state_dict())

    # create evl_Q_value tensor
    evl_Q_value = self.evl_net(s_v).gather(0,a_v) #  size: [batch_size,6].gather() -> [batch_size,1] Type: Tensor
    
    # correctly transform next_s_v into tensor：
    nonDone_index = th.LongTensor(tuple([i for i,x in enumerate(dones) if x!=True])).to(self.device)
    tgt_Q_value = th.zeros(batch_size).to(device) 

    true_next_s_v = list(filter((None).__ne__,next_s_v)) # pop the "None" elements  
    true_next_s_v = th.FloatTensor(true_next_s_v).to(self.device) # size: [notDone_batch_size,4,84,84]
    # print(true_next_s_v.shape)

    tgt = self.tgt_net(true_next_s_v).max(1)[0].detach() # size [1,notDone_batch_size] Type: Tensor
    # print(tgt.shape)
    
    # update tgt_Q_value
    tgt_Q_value[nonDone_index] = tgt
    tgt_Q_value = r_v + self.gamma * tgt_Q_value
    tgt_Q_value = tgt_Q_value.reshape(batch_size,1) #  size: [batch_size, 1] cannot be back propagated
    # print(tgt_Q_value)
    
    self.optimal.zero_grad()
    loss = self.cert(evl_Q_value, tgt_Q_value)
    loss.backward()
    
    # constrain the gradient from explosion
    for p in self.evl_net.parameters():
      p.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
    
    self.optimal.step()

    # decrease fire
    if(self.epsilon > self.min_epsilon):
      self.epsilon *= self.dr
```

In the main training progress, I set the batch size increasing from 32 to 64 for accelerating the operation. The CNN will be updated each four episodes. The statistic information will be printed each ten episodes.

```
# set GPU device to cuda
device = th.device("cuda:0" if th.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# set episode step and batch_size
episodes = 5000
batch_size = 32

env = gym.make("PongNoFrameskip-v4")
env = gym.wrappers.AtariPreprocessing(env, noop_max=30, frame_skip=4, screen_size=84, terminal_on_life_loss=True, grayscale_obs=True, grayscale_newaxis=False, scale_obs=False)
    
# create frame stack for the input image data (size: (4,84,84))
env = gym.wrappers.FrameStack(env, 4)
channels = env.observation_space.shape[0]
a_space = env.action_space.n

agent = Agent(channels, a_space, device)
agent.load(channels, a_space)

# testing start:

for e in range(episodes):

  # step 1: reset the agent at the beginning
  s = np.array(env.reset())
  img = plt.imshow(env.render('rgb_array'))
  done = False
  score = 0

  while not done:
  
    # step 2: iterate actions
    a = agent.select(th.Tensor(s).unsqueeze(0).to(device),a_space)
    next_s, reward, done, _ = env.step(a)
    if(done==True):
      reward = -1.0
      next_s = None
    else:
      next_s = np.array(next_s)  
    # print(next_s.shape)

    # step 3: record the data into buffer
    dataset = (s,a,next_s,reward,done)
    agent.record(dataset)

    # step 4: update state steps
    s = next_s
    score += reward

  # step 5: training and update CNN by each 4 episodes
  if(len(agent.memory) > batch_size and e % 4 == 0):
    agent.train(channels,batch_size)
    agent.save()
  
  # appendix 1: at the beginning increase batch_size from 32 to 64
  if(batch_size < 64):
    batch_size += 1

  # appendix 2: return score by each 10 episodes
  if(e % 10 == 0 and len(agent.memory)>batch_size):
    print("episodes:",e,"score:",score,"epsilon: {:.2}".format(agent.epsilon))
```

During running there is not any error information reminded. However, the agent does not perform as well as expected. After 1000 episodes, it still returns minus score as it did at the very start. The output is like this:

```
episodes: 800 score: -20.0 epsilon: 0.37
episodes: 810 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.36
episodes: 820 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.36
episodes: 830 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.35
episodes: 840 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.35
episodes: 850 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.34
episodes: 860 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.34
episodes: 870 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.34
episodes: 880 score: -20.0 epsilon: 0.33
episodes: 890 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.33
episodes: 900 score: -20.0 epsilon: 0.32
episodes: 910 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.32
episodes: 920 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.31
episodes: 930 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.31
episodes: 940 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.31
episodes: 950 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.3
episodes: 960 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.3
episodes: 970 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.3
episodes: 980 score: -21.0 epsilon: 0.29
```

I rechecked the structure of the model according to the algorithm theory but found nothing different. I hope to get some advice and help on how to deal with this problem.

Comment: In `Agent.select` greedy action always equal to 0, so squeeze before converting to list

Comment: In `Agent.train` while computing `evl_Q_value` to take corresponding actions method `gather` should be called with `dim = 1` not 0

Comment: In current training only thing that `evl_net` learns to do is to predict random values returned by `tgt_net`. Random because its weights initialized randomly and they do not updated during training.

Comment: @draw Thank you for your answer, friend and sorry for such late reply. I changed the list into numpy array[0]. For this change I used np.argmax() function instead of index(), and fix the evl_Q_value mistake you mentioned (sorry, I didn't not see your comment when I first time replied you). However, I'm afraid I do not quite understand you last comment about the evl_net. Could you please talk about more details? Many thanks!

Comment: @draw Do you mean that the parameters in tgt_net will be initialized randomly after loading evl_tgt each time? Am I correctly understand what you said?

Comment: Yeah, if loading weights, then no problem, I've just skipped that line, so my last comment not relevant

Comment: @draw Thanks. I've rechecked the part of loading parameters.  However, I found it still does not work for the score. I think it should be at least improved slightly after 400 episodes although it takes commonly millions of steps. But instead, the score still stays around -21 after 600 episodes. Is this because the statistic data (scores) is not suitable or any other reasons? Thank you.

Comment: @draw I'm afraid I should tell more details of what I said. I rechecked the two variables evl_Q_value and tgt_Q_value, which soon start to decrease after an short increasement. Especially, the tgt_Q_value becomes lower then evl_Q_value after about 100 episodes. Could you please give me any advice on why it happened and how to fix this problem if it is an incorrect condition? thanks!

Comment: An extra thing I'd do is increasing the replay buffer size, for a successful training you'll need at least 100k samples. 
Also if not using a distributed approach (generating non correlated samples from multiple processes) I guess it will take much more than just 1000 episodes.
You can check my DQN implementation for SpaceInvaders here: https://github.com/Guillem96/space-invaders-jax

Comment: @Guillem Thank you! when I fixed my model I got another problem. I found there are lots of times the evl_Q_value instantly decreased to zero. I doubt that the problem may be appeared in the CNN. Is this because the gradient explosion? how can I fix it?